# Three.js: making bounding box

Tags: three.js, bounding-box

In my program, I am trying to make bounding box around a point cloud. I have calculated the opposite vertices for this purpose.

[Here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/BoxGeometry), documentation for BoxGeomtery is available. But I am not able to understand the constructor. Constructor takes width,height, depth as inputs. But what about location of the box. Where in the scene would this box be created?I want bounding box to be defined by two vertices I have.

Edit:

```
var geometry = new THREE.Box3(mn,mx);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xfffff, wireframe: true});
var bBox = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(bBox);
```

mn,mx are vertices of the box.
Above code gives error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: object.geometry.addEventListener is not a function

Comment: `THREE.Box3` is not a geometry and cannot be used this way.

Answer (score 1):

`BoxGeomtery` is a geometry generator. What you are looking for is [Box3](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3), `three.js`'s AABB implementation. You can use [Box3.setFromObject](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3.setFromObject) to generate a bounding box for a 3D object.

```
const aabb = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( points );
```

You can then use [Box3.getCenter](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Box3.getCenter) to retrieve the center of the box.

Comment: It's an instance of `THREE.Points`.

Comment: You can't use an instance of `THREE.Box3`  as a geometry object. `THREE.Box3` is a bounding box or bounding volume that you can use e.g. for fast intersection tests. If you just want to visualize a bounding box of an object, use `THREE.BoxHelper` like in this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_helpers