# How does threejs get the outermost size of the model

Tags: three.js

I want to get the outermost dimension of the imported model, which is equivalent to a cube wrapping the model, and then mark the length, width and height of the model. How can I achieve this better?

Comment: Seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998810/three-js-making-bounding-box) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111504/three-js-is-there-any-way-to-take-bounding-box-for-group) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d) might lead to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the size of a model you need first to get the bounding box and then measure the size. For that you need to create a `Box3` with the model through `Box3.setFromObject(model)`, and then use `Box3.getSize(new THREE.Vector3())`.

I have created a sample for you in [fiddle on how to load a model and get the size](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/d1kn9a35/34/). I also added a helper for clarity.

The relevant code is the following:

```js
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load(
'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf',
    function(gltf) {
        model = gltf.scene;
        this.scene.add(model);
        let bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(model);
        let helper = new THREE.Box3Helper(bbox, new THREE.Color(0, 255, 0));
        let size = bbox.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()); // HEREyou get the size
        scene.add(helper);
    }
);
```

[image]

PS.- If this answer solves your question, please mark it as **answer accepted** in that way it will also help other users to know it was the right solution

Comment: Thank you very much. This really works. I will make good use of this method and try to improve my project